# Wifi extremely slow on ubuntu 16.04, tried almost everything and still not working properly

Tags: 16.04, wireless, internet

I have a Dell Latitude E6400 laptop and my wifi is extremely slow, it takes ages to load some pages not to speak about videos. All other devices on the same wifi have proper internet speed

**This is the output for**

```
sudo lshw -C network

 *-network
        description: Wireless interface
        physical id: 2
        logical name: wlan0
        serial: 00:23:4d:b3:4d:ba
        capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
        configuration: broadcast=yes driver=b43 driverversion=4.10.0-30-generic firmware=666.2 ip=192.168.0.31
 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
```

**Output for iwconfig:**

```
 enp0s25   no wireless extensions.

 wlan0     IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"UPC6750748"  
           Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.462 GHz  Access Point: FC:B4:E6:8D:C2:D0   
           Bit Rate=54 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
           Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
           Power Management:off
           Link Quality=59/70  Signal level=-51 dBm  
           Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
           Tx excessive retries:229  Invalid misc:320   Missed beacon:0

 lo        no wireless extensions.
```

**Output for lsusb:**

```
 Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub 
 Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub 
 Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub 
 Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub 
 Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub 
 Bus 005 Device 002: ID 0a5c:5800 Broadcom Corp. BCM5880 Secure Applications Processor 
 Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub 
 Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub 
 Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

**rfkill list all**

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN   
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no 
1: dell-wifi: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
```

Please help. I tried loads of tips from the internet, but still no improvement.

I also read a tip about using wicd but it is not showing my wireless connection....

Output for **lspci -knn | grep Net -A3**

```
 00:19.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation 82567LM Gigabit
 Network Connection [8086:10f5] (rev 03)    Subsystem: Dell 82567LM
 Gigabit Network Connection [1028:0233]     Kernel driver in use: e1000e
    Kernel modules: e1000e 00:1a.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel
 Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #4 [8086:2937]
 (rev 03)
 -- 0c:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4322 802.11a/b/g/n Wireless LAN Controller [14e4:432b] (rev 01)  Subsystem: Dell Wireless 1510 Wireless-N WLAN Mini-Card [1028:000d]     Kernel
 driver in use: b43-pci-bridge  Kernel modules: ssb
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3` terminal command.

Comment: I edited the question

Comment: Are there any drivers installed for it?

Comment: how can i check it?

Answer (score 0):

I have the exact same setting (BCM4322 and 1510 Wireless-N WLAN Mini-Card) and I had the exact same problem.

I hunted a bit around and what seemed to help so far was to reinstall the related kernel modul:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall bcmwl-kernel-source
```

I hope this helps.